# How to force wildcards into --report caption

Tags: report, snakemake

I am using `snakemake --report` (v5.9.1) to create .html reports for pipeline/results. However I cannot use wildcards in the `caption` parameter of `report()`.

Here is a short example that works, without using wildcards in `caption`

```
rule all:
     input: expand("doit.{role}", role=["founder","offspring"])
rule doit:
      output: report(touch("doit.{role}"),caption="doit.rst")
      run: print(output[0])
```

Now, what I want/need is a separate caption for `founder` and `offspring` .
I have tried to simply add the `{role}`wildcard to the `caption`:

```
      output: report(touch("doit.{role}"),caption="doit.{role}.rst")
```

but that gives an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sandBox/doit.{role}.rst'
```

but **only** when generating the hmtl-file by running `snakemake --report` . (Running the pipeline is OK).

It seems that `output` wildcards are not evaluated/substituted when `caption`is parsed.

I am using caption-functionality to display short results, as well as ordering the results in the .html report. (related to [Snakemake report: How to show results in pipeline order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193293/snakemake-report-how-to-show-results-in-pipeline-order) ).

Can anyone suggest a work-around or a better pattern for what I am trying to do?